# Is there a way to find the best individual from a list of individuals and then append that to a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, greedy

I am setting up a list in which I have several individuals with programming skills and their going rates. I am in a bind currently, because I am trying to find the best individual from that list approximately, based on their skills covered per dollar. what algorithm should i use to evaluate the individuals in isolation?

I keep trying to get the for loop to iterate but it doesnt move positionally. It ends after it looks at just the first cell.

```
jess = (["php", "java"], 200)

clark = (["php", "c++", "go"], 1000)

john = (["lua"], 500)

cindy = (["php", "go", "word"], 240)

candidates = [jess, clark, john, cindy]

project = ["php", "java", "c++", "lua", "go"]

def team_of_best_individuals(project, candidates):       

##note that in the list candidates, I tried to divide the number of items in the tuple by the cost, in order to find the skill per dollar

   def team_of_best_individuals(project, candidates):
   skillList = []
   for name in (candidates):
       len(name)
       for skill in name[0]:
            skillList.append(skill)

            if len(skillList) == len(name):
                num_of_skills=len(skillList)
                cost = name[1]
                num_skill_per_dollar = num_of_skills/cost
                return num_skill_per_dollar, candidates[0:4]
print("skill per dollar="+str(team_of_best_individuals(project, candidates)))
```

the expected (output) has to be the person who covers the most number of skills per dollar. the return value has to be the positional integer of the person in the list.

for example

```
0 - 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice elegant answer @Mark Meyer,
I would like to add just a point here that I believe is missing in your question. It needs to look for the skills that are part of the project. If any skill that candidate has is not part of this, it has to be discounted for.
I tried writing something that will do that.As he pointed out it may be worthwhile to have candidate names separately instead of variable name.

```
jess = (["php", "java"], 200)

clark = (["php", "c++", "go"], 1000)

john = (["lua"], 500)

cindy = (["php", "go", "word"], 240)

candidates = [jess, clark, john, cindy]

project = ["php", "java", "c++", "lua", "go"]

def team_of_best_individuals(project, candidates):
    best = ('A', 0)
    for ind, candidate in enumerate(candidates):
        skills = candidate[0]
        skillperdollar = len([skill for skill in skills if skill in project])/candidate[1]
        if skillperdollar > best[1]:
            best = (ind, skillperdollar)
    return best
```

Comment: That's a good point. I didn't see anything about that reading the text of the question, but you are probably correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `max()` and pass `no_of_languages/cost` as the key. It would be easier if the names are part of the data not  not the variable names. But if you need to deal with indexes, you can enumerate the list and return the correct index:

```
jess = (["php", "java"], 200)    
clark = (["php", "c++", "go"], 1000)
john = (["lua"], 500)
cindy = (["php", "go", "word"], 240)

candidates = [jess, clark, john, cindy]
m = max(enumerate(candidates), key=lambda cand: len(cand[1][0])/cand[1][1])
m[0] # 3 m[1] is the tuple
```

Including the name in the data and using something like a `namedtuple` helps the readability of the code a lot:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Candidate = namedtuple('Candidate', ('name', 'languages', 'cost'))

candidates = [
    Candidate('jess',["php", "java"], 200),
    Candidate('clark', ["php", "c++", "go"], 1000),
    Candidate('john',["lua"], 500),
    Candidate('cindy', ["php", "go", "word"], 240)
]

max(candidates, key=lambda cand: len(cand.languages)/cand.cost)
#Candidate(name='cindy', languages=['php', 'go', 'word'], cost=240)
```

Edit based on @Vasus-devon's mention:

You can find the intersetion of the projects and the skill using python's sets in the intersection operator `&`. To find the best match only counting skills that intersect with the project you can calculate the length of

```
set(project) & set(candidate.languages)
```

Computing that gives:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Candidate = namedtuple('Candidate', ('name', 'languages', 'cost'))
project = ["php", "java", "c++", "lua", "go"]

project_set = set(project) # make a set from projects

candidates = [Candidate('jess',["php", "java"], 200),
Candidate('clark', ["php", "c++", "go"], 1000),
Candidate('john',["lua"], 500),
Candidate('cindy', ["php", "go", "word"], 240)
]

# calculate project_set intersected with set(cand.languages)
max(candidates, key=lambda cand: len(project_set & set(cand.languages))/cand.cost)
```

result:

```
Candidate(name='jess', languages=['php', 'java'], cost=200)
```